# R programming, webscraping- I can not get a link from html

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8qUy.png)

I am trying to get this html, but there is no class name.
How could I do that?

That is my code in R:

```
link <- read_html('https://www.coffeedesk.pl/kawa/')

link %>% html_nodes('div.product-title a') %>%
html_attr('href')

link_www <- paste0("https://www.coffeedesk.pl", link)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using xpath to parse htmls:

```
library(magrittr)
url <-"https://www.coffeedesk.pl/kawa/"

x <- xml2::read_html(url)

links <- xml2::xml_find_all(x, "//div[@class = 'product-title']//a") %>% 
         xml2::xml_attr("href") %>% 
         paste0("https://www.coffeedesk.pl",.)
```